# Why the result of C loop increment is random

Tags: c

As C language beginner, I wrote a loop demo program.
But the results are always random, I want to know reason.

code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int num;
   while (1000000 > num) {
       num++;
   }
   printf("num %d\n", num);
   return 0;
}
```

results:

```sh
> gcc main.c -o main
> ./main
num 324399570
> ./main
num 166920658
> ./main
num 354193874
```

gcc version: stable 9.2.0 (bottled)

Comment: You don't initialize `num`; you get a quasi-random starting point.  Print it before the loop to see why you get nonsense.

Comment: Try: `int num = 0;`

Comment: It's not *random*, it's *arbitrary*. The value of `num` could be anything. You can't assume either that it is 0 or that it isn't. A conforming implementation could, for example, always set it to 42.

Comment: @KeithThompson or format the hard drive, or run forever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should have been a warning when you compiled about using an uninitialized variable. Change it to:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int num = 0;
   while (1000000 > num) {
       num++;
   }
   printf("num %d\n", num);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are right, and I didn't get any warn at compile time. Do you know what gcc options can make gcc prompt such errors?

Comment: @joaner Use `-Wall` to get the warnings. Add `-Werror` if you want the warnings to cause the build to fail.

Answer (score 1):

because

```
int num;
```

not equal 0.
I found it in c++ too;

Answer (score 0):

Replace `int num;` with `int num = 0;`
As you should initialise the variable before using, otherwise the variable will have garbage value.